# SQL INNER JOIN returns foreign key value instead of primary key value

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have a Flask api where I'm returning products from one of the endpoints and I'm using an `INNER JOIN` query to get the category and user info. This is my endpoint:

```
# Return all products
@products_api.route('/v1/resources/products/all', methods=['GET'])
def api_all():
    conn = databaseConnection()
    cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
    sql_all_products = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM products a INNER JOIN users b ON a.user_id = b.id INNER JOIN product_categories c ON a.product_category_id = c.category_id ORDER BY a.id, b.id;')
    all_products = cur.fetchall()
    return jsonify(all_products)
```

The response is this:

```
[
      {
      "available_from": "Fri, 20 Sep 2019 11:00:00 GMT",
      "available_until": "Wed, 25 Sep 2019 12:00:00 GMT",
      "avatar_url": null,
      "category_id": 1,
      "category_name": "Power Tools",
      "created_date": "Mon, 16 Sep 2019 02:55:48 GMT",
      "description": "The desc.",
      "email": "benj@example.com",
      "email_confirmation_sent_time": "Mon, 16 Sep 2019 16:10:35 GMT",
      "email_confirmed": true,
      "email_confirmed_time": null,
      "firstname": "Ben",
      "id": 32,
      "is_draft": false,
      "last_updated_date": "Mon, 16 Sep 2019 02:55:48 GMT",
      "location": "Johannesburg",
      "parent_id": null,
      "product_category_id": 1,
      "quantity": 2,
      "quantity_available": 2,
      "rental_price": "40",
      "replacement_value": "600",
      "surname": "Jay",
      "title": "The title",
      "user_id": 32,
      "username": "test-user"
   },
      {
      "available_from": "Fri, 20 Sep 2019 00:00:00 GMT",
      "available_until": "Mon, 23 Sep 2019 00:00:00 GMT",
      "avatar_url": null,
      "category_id": 1,
      "category_name": "Power Tools",
      "created_date": "Mon, 16 Sep 2019 02:55:48 GMT",
      "description": "The test description.",
      "email": "benj@example.com",
      "email_confirmation_sent_time": "Mon, 16 Sep 2019 16:10:35 GMT",
      "email_confirmed": true,
      "email_confirmed_time": null,
      "firstname": "Ben",
      "id": 32,
      "is_draft": false,
      "last_updated_date": "Mon, 16 Sep 2019 02:55:48 GMT",
      "location": "Sandton",
      "parent_id": null,
      "product_category_id": 1,
      "quantity": 2,
      "quantity_available": 2,
      "rental_price": "60",
      "replacement_value": "400",
      "surname": "Jay",
      "title": "The test product",
      "user_id": 32,
      "username": "test-user"
   }
]
```

In my expected response the id would contain the primary key value of the `products` table but instead it returns the primary key value of the `user` table (32). How can I change this so that the `id` value in the response is the product id and not the `user_id` value?

EDIT - Here are the columns:

`users`

```
id, username, firstname, surname, email, password, email_confirmation_sent_time, email_confirmed, email_confirmed_time, avatar_url, created_date, last_updated_date
```

`products`

```
id, product_category_id, user_id, title, location, description, rental_price, quantity, quantity_available, replacement_value, available_from, available_until, is_draft, created_date, last_updated_date
```

`product_categories`

```
category_id, category_name, parent_id
```

Comment: which are the columns in the 3 tables?

Comment: Edited the question now to add columns.

Comment: A [mre] please. Including correct tags.

Comment: What do you mean, "the id would contain the primary key value of the products table"? Which id column? What are the PKs of those tables? The SQL asked for all columns of all rows that can be made by appending a row from each table where the 2 ON conditions apply. Your JSON is not keeping all the columns returned from the query.

Comment: The ```id``` column of the ```products``` table (which is also the primary key in the ```products``` table). @bhuvnesh-pattnaik's solution below is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply get data from 1st or primary table and for rest of the tables,
get only selected columns only those what you want if necessary.

try this

`SELECT a.*, b.id as userID, b.username, b.firstname, b.surname, b.email, b.password, b.email_confirmation_sent_time, b.email_confirmed, b.email_confirmed_time, b.avatar_url, b.created_date, b.last_updated_date, c.category_id, c.category_name, c.parent_id FROM products a INNER JOIN users b ON a.user_id = b.id INNER JOIN product_categories c ON a.product_category_id = c.category_id ORDER BY a.id, b.id;`

Comment: Please read the edit help re code blocks & look at the formatted output before you post. Please explain how this answers the question.